# Apache RewriteRule Flag error

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm having problems with the follow code:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^thing/([^/]+)/?$  index.php?t=$1 [B]
```

I'm getting "500 Internal Server Error"

The error log says:

```
RewriteRule: unknown flag 'B'
```

I've check my Apache version:

```
[root@server ~]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Jan 21 2009 22:00:55
```

What am I missing?

(Note: the page loads without the [B] flag)

Comment: For those with a CentOs server, I was able to upgrade to 2.2.8 using this YUM repo: http://jasonlitka.com/yum-repository/. If your server is setup with Plesk, you'll need to do this as well: http://kb.parallels.com/en/762

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[B] was new in 2.2.7.

Comment: *Whacks Apache with a stick for not noting this in the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html *

Comment: Agreed.  Thanks for your help romke.  Now I have to figure out how to upgrade Apache.

Comment: @timborden is there some way to accomplish this pre 2.2.7? i don't have control over a server and the lack of [B] is breaking my proxy.